# Clone one SSD to another and change OS drive letter from G: to C:

Tags: windows-8.1, ssd, clone, migration, drive-letter

**How do I clone my existing Windows 8.1 installation to a new SSD and change the volume drive letter to `C:`?**

I have Windows 8.1 installed on SSD as drive `G:`. Every now and than I come across a program that demands that I have the OS installed on drive C: and it's a pain to skip all *No disc in drive C:* messages.

My current 60 GB SSD is nearly full so I'm going to buy a 240 GB one. I want to transfer my OS image to the new drive and if possible change the drive letter to C:. I've seen that there are some programs that might do this such as Samsung data migration tool, but I don't know if it will change the drive letters.

If I can't clone to a new drive *and* change the drive letter, how can I forbid the OS from assigning letter `C:` to other drives (at least removable ones)? Occasionally it assigns my smartphone drive C: when I connect it for USB charging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're probably out of luck on *changing* the drive letter (Windows will not change the drive letter of a system or boot partition, and trying to force it will lead to issues, because paths are already set up to point to `G:`). However, you *can* point a drive letter to a folder using the `subst` command; in particular, you can assign `C:` as a virtual drive pointing to `G:\`. When I had this exact issue on my last computer (with the system on the `V:` drive), using `subst` got installers to work right: they tried to install to `C:\whatever`, which the system automatically converted to `V:\whatever`.

The downsides are that this doesn't persist across reboots, and it seems to be user-specific, and also different between programs running without admin privileges and programs run as administrator (with UAC on, in Windows 7, at least). To solve both these problems, I created two batch files, each saying

```
subst C: V:\
```

I put them both in my startup items, and set one to run as administrator. I got a UAC prompt every reboot to run that one, but it makes installers work.

After doing a bit of searching just now, I also discovered the following thing you might want to try (try these before you clone, incidentally): you can use the registry to assign this at startup, by putting the following in a .REG file:

```
REGEDIT4 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices] 
"C:"="\\??\\G:"
```

Copy that into a text file, save the file as "fixdrive.reg" or some such. Double-clock to apply the changes to the Registry; that should get that mapping to be applied systemwide at boot, which would be better.

Comment: Thanks. That might help! But will it be "silent" or will it create new virtual drive C: with same contents as G: in my computer and folder lists?

Comment: IIRC (I now have a new computer), it creates a C: drive in My Computer with the same contents as the "real" drive; you just ignore C: and pay attention to G:.